# Extract latest multiple values from different columns using a Sql in ms sql 2012?

Tags: sql

I have got a table with columns

```
(Account_Id, Date_Added, Date_Cleared, Added_Value, Cleared_Value)
```

For each `Account_Id` there are list of transactions with different dates and values. Would it be possible to extract latest `Date_Added` and its value and  latest `Date_Cleared` and its value using only one SQL statement. Sample table is below

```
Account_Id  dateadded   datecleared clearedvalue    addedvalue
12546       22/08/2014  NULL            0           13.66
12546       29/10/2012  NULL            0           156.97
12546       23/05/2014  NULL            0           84.77
12546       04/05/2012  NULL            0           122.86
12546       04/11/2011  NULL            0           178.72
12546       23/05/2014  NULL            0           13.66
12546       06/08/2012  NULL            0           156.97
12546       18/06/2011  18/07/2011      117.76      84.77
12546       19/08/2011  26/09/2011      7.71        224.78
12546       18/07/2011  26/09/2011      48.63       120.04
12546       19/07/2011  26/09/2011      13.66       122.86
12546       04/07/2013  23/05/2014      120.04      48.63
12546       06/01/2014  23/05/2014      122.86      13.66
12546       04/04/2013  23/05/2014      178.72      156.97
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
;WITH cte
 AS
 (
   SELECT Account_Id AS Account_Id
       ,MAX(Date_Added) AS AddedDate
       ,MAX(Date_Cleared) AS ClearedDate
   FROM theTable
   GROUP BY Account_Id
 )
 SELECT cte.Account_Id
        ,added.AddedDate
        ,cleared.ClearedDate
        ,added.Added_Value
        ,cleared.Cleared_Value
 FROM cte 
    LEFT JOIN theTable AS added
    ON added.Account_Id = cte.Account_Id
       AND added.AddedDate = cte.AddedDate
    LEFT JOIN theTable AS cleared
    ON cleared.Account_Id = cte.Account_Id
       AND cleared.ClearedDate = cte.AddedDate
```